# mysql query with multiple groups?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that gets product IDs based on keywords.

```
SELECT indx_search.pid
FROM indx_search
LEFT JOIN word_index_mem ON (word_index_mem.word = indx_search.word)
WHERE indx_search.word = "phone"
GROUP BY indx_search.pid
ORDER BY indx_search.pid ASC
LIMIT 0,20
```

This works well but now I'm trying to go a step further and implement "price range" into this query.

```
CREATE TABLE `price_range` (
 `pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `range_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This table simply contains product IDs and a range_id. The price range values are stored here:

```
CREATE TABLE `price_range_values` (
 `ID` tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `rangeFrom` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `rangeTo` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=32 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I want to GROUP price_range.range_id with COUNT() of how many products match the certain price range within the current query. I still want to receive my 20 results of product IDs.

So something along the lines of:

```
SELECT indx_search.pid, price_range.range_id as PriceRangeID, COUNT(price_range.range_id) as PriceGroupTotal
FROM indx_search
LEFT JOIN windex_mem ON ( windex_mem.word = indx_search.word )
LEFT JOIN price_range ON ( price_range.pid = indx_search.pid )
WHERE indx_search.word = "memory"
GROUP BY indx_search.pid, PriceRangeID
ORDER BY indx_search.pid ASC
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Is this possible to accomplish without busting an additional query?

Comment: if you can make a price column in products table that can ease a bit

Comment: there's already a price column in product table. am i doing this the wrong way then? i access the product table after i get all my product IDs.. join seems to make it wayy slower

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a subquery with a LIMIT clause, e.g. -

```
SELECT
  i_s.pid, p_r.range_id as PriceRangeID, COUNT(p_r.range_id) as PriceGroupTotal
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM indx_search WHERE i_s.word = 'memory' ORDER BY i_s.pid ASC LIMIT 0 , 20) i_s
LEFT JOIN
  windex_mem w_m ON w_m.word = i_s.word
LEFT JOIN
  price_range p_r ON p_r.pid = i_s.pid
GROUP BY
  i_s.pid, PriceRangeID
```

Comment: the problem is, the sub-query will return only 20 results. i wanna process the entire, say, 15000 results that match the keyword.